# How do I get ajax to intermittently call my php?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter

I have ajax that is communicating with php to receive tweets from a twitter account. The code is working fine.
The only thing is I want the ajax to intermittently call the php so that any updated tweets automatically come back and get printed to my page without having to refresh or re-enter a twitter id. 
Do I need to keep calling the getStatuses() function or something?
Or do I need to use the getUpdates() which I have started to make somehow?
Here are my ajax functions:

```
 // the setInterval function added in the getStatusesX function
function getStatusesX()
{
setInterval(getStatuses(),300000);
}

  //Create a cross-browser XMLHttp Request object
function getXMLHttp() {

    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        XMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
       XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    return XMLHttp;
}

 //function that searches for the tweets via php
function getStatuses(){

      XMLHttp1 = getXMLHttp();
      var userID = document.getElementById("userid").value;

      //ajax call to a php file that will extract the tweets
      XMLHttp1.open( 'GET', 'twitterTest2.php?userid='+userID, true);

      // Process the data when the ajax object changes its state
      XMLHttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if( XMLHttp1.readyState == 4 ) {
            if( XMLHttp1.status ==200 ) {  //no problem has been detected

         document.getElementById("tweetbox").innerHTML=XMLHttp1.responseText;

            }
         }
       }
       XMLHttp1.send(null);
}

//function to intermittently call php to check for updated tweets?
function updateInfo() { 
    if(XMLHttp1.readyState == 4) { 

        document.getElementById("tweetbox").innerHTML=XMLHttp1.responseText;

    } 
}

</script>
```

I then added the getStatusesX() function to my form as follows:

```
<form>
Input Twitter ID: <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid">  
<button type="button" onClick="getStatusesX()";>Get recent  tweets</button>
</form>
```

It's still not working. Am i using the setInterval in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` functions.

From what I can see in your code, `getStatuses` has too much responsability since in addition of getting the data, it also modifies the `DOM`.

I would suggest something like:

```
function getStatuses(callback) {
    //...
    XMLHttp1.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //...
        callback && callback(XMLHttp1); //execute callback if any
    };
}

function updateStatuses(callback) {
    getStatuses(function (xhr) {
        document.getElementById("tweetbox").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        callback && callback;
    });
}

//this function update the statuses and as soon as it's finished, it sets
//a timeout to redo the process in ~10 seconds.
function startUpdatingStatuses() {

    updateStatuses(function () {
        setTimeout(startUpdatingStatuses, 10000);
    });
}

startUpdatingStatuses(); //kick-start everything
```

Comment: just added a setinterval function, didn't see your full reply. I will look at it now.

Comment: what does the 'callback && callback' do?

Comment: thanks it helped, i'll accept it. sorry im not great at coding just learning. Finding it difficult to follow what you suggest. I tried to implement it but it didn't work.

Comment: do you see how i tried to use the setInterval above? should that work?

Comment: @user1835504, you need to pass the function **reference** to the `setInterval` function, not the result of the function call. `setInterval(getStatuses, 300000);`